# Programmatically changing the 'Activities I am following' under Newsfeed Settings in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2010

is it possible to programatically select/deselect activities I am following on the news feed preferences page under MySites? I want to be able switch on/off notifications for both custom events and those provided by Sharepoint 2010 out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UserProfileManager class to get a specific UserProfile and do this.

Comment: Hi Doug, do you have some code demonstrating this? I tried to explore the UserProfile class but didn't find any useful property or method

Comment: Use UserProfile["SPS-Interests"] to access interests.

Comment: Thanks for showing the ways Doug, I will continue looking further further.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check "Using Activity Feeds with Object Model" topic under SharePoint SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426881.aspx